# Center section with number after prewitten text and in a new line the section caption

Tags: sectioning, numbering, line-breaking, titlesec, center

I am a beginner at LaTeX, and i was wondering how should i make a section with numbering following a prewriting "text", and a in a new line (the text i want to add in the section{}, all center.

The closer i got with the following code, was this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\center\bfseries}{Cláusula \arabic{section} \newline}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

    \section{ \begin{center}
            Objectivo
    \end{center}}\label{subsec:first}
    Some text from section 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use formatting commands like `\begin{center}...\end{center}` inside `\section{...}` or it'll screw up the table of contents and things like that; instead use titlesec to define how you want the headings to look.

You should use `\centering` rather than `\center` in that context, and should specify the "shape" parameter for the `\titlesec` command to get the right kind of paragraph formatting.

It was a little unclear to me from the wording of your question whether or not you wanted "Cláusula 1" above "Objectivo" or vice-versa.

If "Cláusula 1" goes first, then you can use the "display" shape like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[display]{\centering\large\bfseries}{Cláusula \thesection}{1ex}{}

\begin{document}

    \section{Objectivo}\label{subsec:first}
    Some text from section 
\end{document}
```

Adjust `\large` for the font size you want and 1ex for the spacing between the label and section title to whatever looks good to you.

[image: with the label first]

If you want "Objectivo" first, then  you need to use the "explicit" option to titlesec, the "block" shape and put all the formatting together into the 4th argument to `\titleformat`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\centering\large\bfseries}{#1\\[1ex]Cláusula \thesection}{0ex}{}

\begin{document}

    \section{Objectivo}\label{subsec:first}
    Some text from section 
\end{document}
```

[image: with the title first]

(I should mention I changed the input encoding to utf8 since that what the text copied from this site was encoded as; you may need to change that back depending on the encoding in your actual document, and your editor configuration.)

(And another probably insignificant detail: I changed `\arabic{section}` to `\thesection`: this *probably* doesn't matter, since by default the latter is defined as the former; but if you ever decide to change how you want section numbers formatted you'd need to redefine `\thesection` to get crossreferences right anyway, and then this would keep both the title headings and crossreferences uniform.)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!